# React js importing a large data file (json)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, electron

I have a large JSON file (700MB), it's a search engine index.

the problem is when I run the start script it stays at the compile stage forever.
and I tried to build the whole project but it responds with

> out of  memory (by the way, I give it more than 20 GB, and still the same)

all I want to do  is to  import this file earlier ( unfortunately all features based on this file )

Comment: Are you planning on loading a react application with 700mb+ of data in the built bundle?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I don't know if that possible, but yes 
I m working with elasticlunrJS (search module ), and all it needs is this JSON file,
that's mean I have to deal with large size

Comment: *Typically* you don't put something like that in the app bundle, you load it dynamically (with some caching to prevent needless re-downloads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to reevaluate and re-engineer your architecture and how you handle the data.
The prevelant approach is to have a server with an endpoint providing the data. Your React app should load small in size, and get the data to work with from the endpoint.